Custom form module with file upload returns null value for file after submit
For a job interviewe task, I have to make a drupal module from scratch without the use of external modules. So far it's going okay, for someone who's new with Drupal, but I'm stuck at this point and I don't know how to proceed..
It goes wrong when I want to upload the form with a pdf file. I can select a file and it recognizes the file but when I hit submit, it just fails to actually store the file. It returns a null value when I do a dump and die on the file.
I notice that even when I pass a name attribute, the actual name on the element is files[cv], which is weird because I've never coded that. I tried different approaches but I just can't seem to figure it out..
I'll provide you with my code
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        $form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data");

        // Formvelden
        $form['naam'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => 'Naam',
            '#required' => true,
        ];
        $form['voornaam'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => 'Voornaam',
            '#required' => true,
        ];
        $form['email'] = [
            '#type' => 'email',
            '#title' => 'E-mail',
            '#required' => true,
        ];
        $form['functie'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => 'Functie',
            '#required' => true,
        ];
        $form['motivatie'] = [
            '#type' => 'textarea',
            '#title' => 'Motivatie',
            '#required' => true,
        ];
        $form['cv'] = [
            '#type' => 'managed_file',
            '#title' => 'Upload je CV',
            '#description' => 'De CV moet een PDF bestand zijn',
            '#name' => 'cv',
            '#size' => 40,
            '#upload_validators' => [
                'file_validate_extensions' => ['pdf'],
            ],
            '#default_value' => array(10),
            '#required' => true,
            '#upload_location' => 'public://uploads/',
        ];
        
        // Bevestigen
        $form['submit'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => 'Versturen',
        ];

        return $form;

    }


    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        $values = $form_state->getValues();

        dd($values);

        $this->fileSaveUpload($form_state);

        \Drupal::database()->insert('jobs')->fields([
            'naam' => $values['naam'],
            'voornaam' => $values['voornaam'],
            'email' => $values['email'],
            'functie' => $values['functie'],
            'motivatie' => $values['motivatie'],
            'cv' => $file_name,
        ])->execute();

        
        \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Uw sollicitatie is met succes ingediend. U hoort spoedig van ons terug');

    }

    private function fileSaveUpload(FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        $fid = $form_state->getValue('cv')[0];
        
        if ($fid) {
          $file = File::load($fid);
          if ($file) {
            dd($file);
            $file->setPermanent();
            $file->save();
            $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('Het bestand is succesvol geüpload.'));
          } else {
            $this->messenger()->addError($this->t('Het bestand kon niet worden geladen.'));
          }
        } else {
          $this->messenger()->addError($this->t('Er is geen bestand geüpload.'));
        }

    }


I got it working and the solution will make your head shake.
I used MAMP as the local webserver because I've learned working with it in school on my MacBook so I used the Windows version on my Windows PC. However, I got a lot of connection resets on when I was navigating or triggering functions and I was fed up with it so I decided to use Xampp for Windows en reinstall a new version of drupal and guess what, with some minor tweaks, I got it working!
